# Installing 32-bit SDL2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, 18.04, multiarch

Trying to install `libsdl2-2.0:i386`, I am met with this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-2.0-0:i386' for regex 'libsdl2-2.0'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.27)
                      Depends: libsndio6.1:i386 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Investigating, I find that `sudo apt install libsndio6.1:i386` leads to

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsndio6.1:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.17)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt install libasound2:i386` leads to

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2:i386 : Depends: libasound2-data:i386 (>= 1.1.3-5)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But I hit a dead end because trying to install `libasound2-data:i386` I get

```
Note, selecting 'libasound2-data' instead of 'libasound2-data:i386'
libasound2-data is already the newest version (1.1.3-5ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This is on a fresh install of Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and the 'broken package' fix from the Software Boutique doesn't help.

EDIT:
I fixed my problem by removing libasound2 and libasound2-data (the 64bit versions) -- without removing dependant packages (which would remove the whole system), and then reinstalling them (again the 64 bit ones). Now the 32bit ones install fine, and SDL2 32bit installs fine. Don't ask me why.

Turns out the version was wrong, but it refused to up/downgrade in Synaptic, so doing it like this was the only way I could see.

However I ran into the same problem trying to install another 32bit library! So, I'll keep this question open if anyone has a permanent solution...

Comment: On my clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE (amd64) I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you forgot to update package lists before installation of packages... Or your mirror is out of sync.

Comment: what is the output of  `dpkg -l "*asound2*"`?